# How to create Json object

Tags: android, json

I have database like which have three coloums( id(integer) , startdate(text), enddate(text),).
I want to read all the entries for these coloums, convert them to Json and send to web url.
I know how read values but did not know how to make Json from these values.
Please any coding help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try:
`

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("id", id);
        object.put("startDate", startDate);
        object.put("endDate", endDate);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Then send the json object via a http post
`

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String message;

        HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);    
 try {
        message = object.toString();


        p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
        p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
            if (resp != null) {
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                    result = true;
            }

            Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }`
```

so if for example you want to create a JSON object containing all the triplets you get from an SQLite db it would be:

```
String query = "SELECT *"+
             "from "+TABLE_NAME;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{});
    Log.d("query",query);

    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        try {
            int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            String startDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("START_DATE"));
            String endDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("END_DATE"));

   object.put("id", id);
    object.put("startDate", startDate);
    object.put("endDate", endDate); }}
```

where ID, START_DATE and END_DATE are the corresponding names of the fields in DB.
I cannot test my code right now but I believe it works

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to make an JSON object:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("id", idValue);
jsonObject.put("startDate", endDateValue);
jsonObject.put("endDate", endDateValue);
```

You can also get the JSON as String by doing:

```
jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) ;)

Comment: when i loop your code, is it make new Json object for second entry...?

Comment: create JSONArray object and insert each one in

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("id", id);
    json.put("startdate", startdate);
    json.put("enddate", enddate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **jackson** library, you can convert a map or java bean to a json string or generate a map or javabean from a json string. you might write a util class:

```
 public class JsonUtil {
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String convertToJsonStr(Object model) throws IOException {
        return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(model);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Map<String, Object> readFromStr(String content) throws IOException {
        return readFromStr(content, Map.class);
    }

    public static <T> T readFromStr(String content, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        return MAPPER.readValue(content, clazz);
    }
}
```